# selecting the first child of a list without including the grandchildren

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which I would like to select the `first child` only of an element that is `first child` to appear in blue and the last child that is `fourth child` to be in red.
However the grand children are also selected this way, the children of the second child. first grand child appears in blue while the others appear in red.
is there a way I could only select the children without including the grandchildren.
If anything is not clear just comment below and I will reply as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

```css
.parent > ul > li > ul
{
  display:none;
}
.has_children:hover > ul
{
  display:block;
}
.parent > ul :first-child
{
  color:blue;
}
.parent > ul :last-child
{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent">
<ul>
  <li>first child</li>
  <li class = "has_children">second child
  <ul>
    <li>first grand child</li>
    <li>second grand child</li>
    <li>third grand child</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>third child</li>
  <li>fourth child</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the "first grand child" element blue and "third grand child" red as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.parent > ul > li:first-child
{
  color:blue;
}
.parent > ul > li:last-child
{
  color:red;
}
```

This way, you are selecting the first `li` and the last `li` that comes directly inside the child `ul` of the `.parent` div.

**[CHECK IT OUT](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/jb5h8hgu/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first-child` and `last-child` without select its parent. According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors#first-child):

> :first-child pseudo-class
>
> The :first-child pseudo-class matches an element that is the first
>   child element of some other element.

However, you don't need to use grandparent or parent for selecting the first and last child.

```
li:first-child {
    background: red;
}

li:last-child {
    background: red;
}
```

other solution:

```
li:nth-child(1)

li:nth-of-type(1)
li::nth-last-of-type(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could increase your selectors and use first and last-of-type

```css
.parent > ul > li > ul
{
  display:none;
}
.has_children:hover > ul
{
  display:block;
}
.parent > ul > li:first-of-type
{
  color:blue;
}
.parent > ul > li:last-of-type
{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent">
<ul>
  <li>first child</li>
  <li class = "has_children">second child
  <ul>
    <li>first grand child</li>
    <li>second grand child</li>
    <li>third grand child</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>third child</li>
  <li>fourth child</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.parent > ul > li:first-child {
    color: blue;
}
.parent > ul > li:last-child {
    color: red;
}
```